# Passing an array of ints as an argument in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, parameters, arguments

I made a function in C++ to find the length of an array. I find the `sizeof` the array passed in the argument and divide it by the `sizeof` the variable type. This should work but it always returns 1! Am I missing something obvious? Or does this have to do with pointers and memory? This is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int lengthOf(int arr[]);

    int main() {
        int x[] = {1,2,3,0,9,8};
        int lenX = lengthOf(x);
        cout << lenX;
        return 0;
    }

    int lengthOf(int arr[]) {
        int totalSize = sizeof arr;
        cout << totalSize << endl;
        int elementSize = sizeof(int);

        return totalSize/elementSize;
    }
```

Output (should be 6 instead of 1):

```
    4
    1
```

I am fairly new so excuse me if this is a bad question.

Comment: The thing you're missing is that `int arr[]` becomes `int* arr` as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When passing an array as parameter, it always decays into a pointer. If you want to see the size of the array, you need to pass the array by reference, e.g.:

```
template <int Size>
int lengthOf(int (&array)[Size]) {
    return Size;
}
```

Comment: Which leads to the question ;) why there's `std::extent`, but no function for deducing it in the Standard. (Has it been proposed?)

Comment: @DyP: You don't consider `std::extent<decltype(array)>::value` natural to write? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pointer.

(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr))

Comment: As far as I know, sizeof(arr) == sizeof(*arr) as the array degenerates into a pointer when passed as an argument.

Comment: @Quirliom In C++, the problem is not the argument (what you pass) but the parameter (what the function expects). The function expects `int arr[]`, which is in that context (function parameter) equivalent to `int* arr`.

Comment: Correct.  You can't pass an array of arbitrary size directly to a function; it decays to a pointer, so sizeof(arr) == sizeof(int*).

Answer (score 0):

Even though `int arr[]` looks like you are passing an array, you are actually passing a pointer. `int arr[]` is equivalent to `int* arr` when used as a function parameter, this comes from C.

In C++, if you want to pass an array, the proper way is to do it by reference:

```
template <int N>
int lengthOf(int (&arr)[N]) {
     int totalSize = sizeof arr;
     cout << totalSize << endl;
     int elementSize = sizeof(int);

     return totalSize/elementSize;
}
```